# Jenkins Multipipeline: Ignore User Commit in SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I'm currently trying to replace our old cascading builds with an Multibranch Pipeline.

My Target is an Environment where our whole Project is driven by Jenkinsfiles and Branches or Tags can run as an Continuous Integration / Delivery Pipeline.

We are using SVN which defined an Webhook to trigger Builds on commit, and here results my question:

**How can I Ignore commits from specific Users when I'm using Multibranch Pipeline in Jenkins?**

Edit:

I was trying to reproduce the behavior pointed [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226122247-How-to-Customize-Checkout-for-Pipeline-Multibranch). But I can't get it running with the SubversionSCM.

```
checkout(
[
    $class: 'SubversionSCM',
    additionalCredentials: scm.additionalCredentials,
    excludedCommitMessages: scm.excludedCommitMessages,
    excludedRegions: scm.excludedRegions,
    excludedRevprop: scm.excludedRevprop,
    excludedUsers: 'batch',  // <<-- this is what I want
    filterChangelog: scm.filterChangelog ,
    ignoreDirPropChanges: scm.ignoreDirPropChanges,
    includedRegions: scm.includedRegions,
    locations: scm.locations,
    workspaceUpdater: scm.workspaceUpdater
]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this Post](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33273?focusedCommentId=284536&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-284536) I tried to adapt the way to extract the **scm.locations** and create the same checkout only with an user exception. But sadly the build continues and ignores the second checkout limitations.

Currently im solving this with manuall adding branches to the pipeline and waiting for further additions to the multipipeline or subversion -plugin.